# Collision detection of two grid locked rectangles Not working

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to recreate the game [RushHour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Hour_(puzzle))
The two rectangles should not be able to go through each other.
Vertical collision detection works but horizontal does not.
Also the bottom rectangle can not move horizontally and the top rectangle can not move vertically.
Is there a way to incorporate the `sizex` and `sizey` variables into the detection?

```js
var row = 6
var column = 6
var actualx = []
var actualy = []
var actualsizex = []
var actualsizey = []
var rx = [4,4]
var ry = [4,5]
var sizex = [1,1]
var sizey = [1,1]
var canmovehori = [1,0]
var canmovevert = [0,1]
var clicked = []
var steps
var objects=1

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  console.log(rx);
  console.log(ry);
  console.log(sizey);
  console.log(sizex)
  console.log(rx.length)
  steps = height/row
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (var x = 0; x < width; x += width / column) {
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y += height / row) {
   stroke(255);
   strokeWeight(1);
   line(x, 0, x, height);
   line(0, y, width, y);
        }
  for (i=0; i < rx.length; i++){
    actualx[i] = steps*rx[i] - steps
    actualy[i] = steps*ry[i] - steps
    actualsizex[i] = sizex[i]*steps
    actualsizey[i] = sizey[i]*steps
    if(clicked[i]==1){
      fill(255,0,0)
    
    }else{
      fill(255)
    }
    rect(actualx[i], actualy[i], actualsizex[i], actualsizey[i]) 
  }
  }
}

function mousePressed(){
  for (i=0; i < rx.length; i++){
    x = actualx[i]
    y = actualy[i]
    w = actualsizex[i]
    h = actualsizey[i]
    if (mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + h){
      console.log('Click')
      for (n=0; n <= objects; n++){
        clicked[n] = 0
      }
      clicked[i] = 1
      console.log(clicked)
    }
  }

}
function keyPressed() {
  selected = clicked.indexOf(1)
  console.log(selected)

  if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    console.log('Left')
    if (rx[selected]  != 1 && canmovehori[selected] == 1){
      rx[selected]--
      colision('L', selected)
    }
    
  }
  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    console.log('right')
    if (rx[selected]+sizex[selected]-1 != 6 && canmovehori[selected] == 1){
      rx[selected]++
      console.log('Passed')
      colision('R', selected)
    }
    
  }
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    console.log('up')
    if (ry[selected] != 1 && canmovevert[selected] == 1){
      ry[selected]--
      console.log('Passed')
      colision('U', selected)
    }
    
  }
  if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    console.log('Down')
    if (ry[selected] +sizey[selected] -1 != 6 && canmovevert[selected] == 1){
      ry[selected]++
      console.log('Passed')
      colision('D', selected)
    }
  
  }
}
function colision(n,s){
  mx=rx[s]
  my=ry[s]
  collidex = rx.indexOf(mx) +1
  collidey = ry.indexOf(my) +1
  console.log(s)
  console.log(collidey)
  console.log(collidex)
  if (collidex != s+1 && collidey != s+1){
    if(n == 'U'){
      ry[s]++
    }
    if(n == 'D'){
      ry[s]--
    }
    if(n == 'L'){
      rx[s]++
    }
    if(n == 'R'){
      rx[s]--
    }
    console.log('Collis')
    
  }else{console.log('All good')}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more like the RushHour game we can encapsulate some of the rules of the game into a Vehicle object. The vehicle can keep track of where it is at on the grid and its own selected state. This allows us to have fewer arrays and overall makes thinking about the game simpler.

This code is not a complete working RushHour game but it does move you closer to a solution.

```js
var rows = 6
var columns = 6
var vehicles = [];
var selectedVehicle;
var vehicleIds = 0; 
var vehicleSize;

var Vehicle = function( row,  col,  direction){
  this.row = row;
  this.col = col;
  this.vehicleId = vehicleIds++;
  this.selectedState = false;
  this.direction = direction;
  this.xPos = col * vehicleSize;
  this.yPos = row * vehicleSize;
};

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  vehicleSize = width/columns;
   vehicles.push(new Vehicle(3,3, "horz"));
   vehicles.push(new Vehicle(4,3, "vert"));
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (var x = 0; x < width; x += width / columns) {
     for (var y = 0; y < height; y += height / rows) {
        stroke(255);
        strokeWeight(1);
        line(x, 0, x, height);
        line(0, y, width, y);
     }
     
    for (i=0; i < vehicles.length; i++){
      let vehicle = vehicles[i];
      if(vehicle.selectedState){
        fill(255,0,0)
      }else{
        fill(255)
      }
      rect(vehicle.col * vehicleSize, vehicle.row * vehicleSize, vehicleSize, vehicleSize) 
    }
  }
}

function mousePressed(){
  for (i=0; i < vehicles.length; i++){
    let vehicle = vehicles[i];
    x = vehicle.xPos;
    y = vehicle.yPos;
    w = vehicleSize;
    h = vehicleSize;
    vehicle.selectedState = false;
    if (mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + h){
      selectedVehicle = vehicle;
      selectedVehicle.selectedState = true;
    }
  }
}
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    if (canMoveLeft(selectedVehicle)){
      selectedVehicle.col--;
      selectedVehicle.xPos -= vehicleSize;
    }
  }
  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    if (canMoveRight(selectedVehicle)){
      selectedVehicle.col++;
      selectedVehicle.xPos += vehicleSize;
    }
  }
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    if (canMoveUp(selectedVehicle)){
      selectedVehicle.row--;
      selectedVehicle.yPos -= vehicleSize;
    }
  }
  if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    if (canMoveDown(selectedVehicle)){
      selectedVehicle.row++;
      selectedVehicle.yPos += vehicleSize;
    }
  }
}

function canMoveLeft(vehicle){
  if (vehicle.col > 0 && vehicle.direction === "horz"){
    for (let i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++){
      let otherVehicle = vehicles[i];
      if (otherVehicle.row === vehicle.row && otherVehicle.col === vehicle.col - 1){
        return false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function canMoveRight(vehicle){
  if (vehicle.col < columns - 1 && vehicle.direction === "horz"){
    for (let i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++){
      let otherVehicle = vehicles[i];
      if (otherVehicle.row === vehicle.row && otherVehicle.col === vehicle.col + 1){
        return false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function canMoveDown(vehicle){
  if (vehicle.row < rows - 1 && vehicle.direction === "vert"){
    for (let i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++){
      let otherVehicle = vehicles[i];
      if (otherVehicle.col === vehicle.col && otherVehicle.row === vehicle.row + 1){
        return false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function canMoveUp(vehicle){
  if (vehicle.row > 0 && vehicle.direction === "vert"){
    for (let i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++){
      let otherVehicle = vehicles[i];
      if (otherVehicle.col === vehicle.col && otherVehicle.row === vehicle.row - 1){
        return false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

To complete the game you will need to extend the code to:

- Handle vehicles that are longer than one square
- Give the user an indication of which way the vehicle moves (left/right or up/down)
- Provide an exit square so the main car can move off of the grid